# Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -stdlib=libc++ xamarin binding

Tags: ios, xamarin, binding

I added "Additional mtouch arguments on ios project.

but got the error "Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD24u.png): -stdlib=libc++"

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5618/error-when-referencing-native-library-c-that-uses-vector may help.

Comment: I added 4 static libraries to the one binding project

"std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
__GLOBAL__sub_I_SW_DownSample.cpp in libG4XSwiper.a(SW_WavBuffer.o)
__GLOBAL__sub_I_SW_ManchesterRealTimeDecoder.mm in libG4XSwiper.a(SW_ManchesterRealTimeDecoder.o)
__GLOBAL__sub_I_SW_ManchesterState.mm in libG4XSwiper.a(SW_ManchesterState.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
__GLOBAL__sub_I_SW_DownSample.cpp in libG4XSwiper.a(SW_DownSample.o)
__GLOBAL__sub_I_SW_FskController.mm in libG4XSwiper.a(SW_FskController.o)
__GLOBAL__sub_I_SW_WavBuffer.mm in libG4XSwiper.a(SW_WavBuffer.o)
__GLOBAL__sub_I_SW_ManchesterRealTimeDecoder.mm in libG4XSwiper.a(SW_ManchesterRealTimeDecoder.o)
__GLOBAL__sub_I_SW_ManchesterState.mm in libG4XSwiper.a(SW_ManchesterState.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)